# MathJax rendering extra line to the right of substitutions

Tags: mathjax

Does anyone know why MathJax is adding the span element that causes the lines to be rendered to the right of all substituted statements?
e.g. https://hepdata.net/record/ins1380234

[image: extra span element added here.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in recent versions of Chrome.  MathJax v2.6.0 includes a work-around for it, so upgrading your site to use the latest 2.6 version should resolve the problem.  See the [MathJax issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1300) for details.